# Using bash to create a directory in HDFS if the directory does not exist

Tags: bash, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I want to test whether a directory exists in the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS). I want to create the directory if it does not exist and do nothing otherwise.

When I modify the code at http://jugnu-life.blogspot.com/2012/10/hadoop-fs-test-example.html:

```
#!/bin/bash
directory=/raw/tool/

if hadoop fs -test –d $directory ; then
    echo "Directory  exists"
else
    hadoop fs -mkdir $directory
    echo "Creating  directory"
fi
```

I get the error:

```
-test: Too many arguments: expected 1 but got 2
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -test -[defsz] <path>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you copied/pasted your example, the - before the d is incorrect. I copied the the command lines from your post, notice how the - before the day expands differently.

```
$ echo -test | od -c
0000000   -   t   e   s   t  \n

$ echo –d | od -c
0000000 342 200 223   d  \n
```

Comment: According to Unicode terminology, this `–` is an _EN DASH_ (U+2013) whereas it should be a plain old `-`, that is _HYPHEN-MINUS_ (U+002D).

Comment: Thank you both for your help catching this!